# Azure FTP Upload speed

Tags: azure, ftp

After a couple of hours of banging my head in an attempt to configure and FTP site in the IIS of our Azure VM I finally managed to do ithttp://www.itq.nl/blogs/post/Walkthrough-Hosting-FTP-on-IIS-75-in-Windows-Azure-VM.aspx. After that I tried to upload our database (.bak) file to the ftp folder of the VM which turned out to be super slow.

We have a 70MB upload speed over a fiber connection but are only getting 56-60 KB/s upload speeds to the server. It is physically located in Southeast Asia but I dont believe that the distance is what's making it so slow.

Are there any configurations I need to change or any known bottlenecks on the Azure side?

Thanks!

Comment: Please see this blog post: http://blog.credera.com/topic/technology-solutions/microsoft-solutions/deciding-on-vm-size-and-instance-count-in-windows-azure/. Bandwidth is dependent on the VM Size.

Comment: We are on the A7 56GB VM but on the free trial subscription, is it a result of the fact we are on a free trial?

Comment: Free Trial has nothing to do with performance (unless you exceed a quote for something).

Comment: Check out the Azure Throughput Analyzer (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/5c8189b9-53aa-4d6a-a086-013d927e15a7/default.aspx) to test your bandwidth to a storage account in Southeast Asia.  This will tell you if the problem is the bandwidth between your location and the datacenter, or if the problem is in your FTP implementation.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar problem but backwards: FTP server on our infrastructure; FTP client on Azure VM - throughput uploading from us to Azure maxing out at 73kbps.  We have 100Mb fiber.

Comment: I have same problem, is there any solution?

Comment: 3 years later, and I have the same problem, and google shows me this with no solution. Learned anything new by now?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit old, but it solves changing ftp to passive mode.

Hope that helps.